# Как ввести enter для завершения программы?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Скопировал пример, но он не работает, хотя должен. Что не так?
В учебнике пример работает, но у меня программа не выводит ничего. Думаю, что может быть мой vs использует другой значок для обозначения ентер (13 я тоже пробовал).     Программа просто не завершается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В примере из учебника вместо cin.get нужно было использовать getcher
но visual studio не запускал программу вообще.

Comment: Вообще-то `\n`...

Comment: Для начала надо привести код в виде текста.

Comment: Код лучше приводить в виде текста, а не в виде картинки. Текст можно скопировать к себе и попробовать запустить, а вот перепечатывать код со скриншота никто не станет.

Comment: А так не пробовали \n?

Answer (score 2):

Замените \r на \n. По поводу знаковых литералов можно посмотреть [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6aw8xdf2(v=vs.120).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(ch == 13) //используется код ANSII (все коды можно посмотреть на википедии)
 cout << "Вы нажали Enter";
```

эквивалентно

```
if(ch == "\n") //используется знаковый литерал (информация о всех литералах есть на msdn)
 cout << "Вы нажали Enter";
```

Comment: Как минимум вы пытаетесь сравнивать символ со строкой. Но даже если будете сравнивать с `'\n'` - то это не эквивалентно, потому что код у `\n` не 13...